# Control Panel, Landscape / Portrait Images

Tags: control-panel, image

How can i achieve that portrait images in Control Panel are shown as portrait images. Now they all are stretched to fit the width of the parent container. This behaviour is only in "Big View" of images.
I use newest Craft CMS 2.6.2791.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. I think this is a bug - raise it as a support ticket through your Control Panel. http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29/how-do-i-submit-a-bug-issue-with-craft

Comment: thx - i just made it.